# how to execute multiple f90 codes simultaneously correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, fortran90

I am trying like this, but sure it is improvable, because the bash can't finish for some reason...

```
  #!/bash/bin

  cd directory
  gfortran -O3 code1.f90 -o a1.out
  gfortran -O3 code2.f90 -o a2.out
  gfortran -O3 code3.f90 -o a3.out
  gfortran -O3 code4.f90 -o a4.out
  gfortran -O3 code5.f90 -o a5.out
  gfortran -O3 code6.f90 -o a6.out

  ./a1.out & ./a2.out & ./a3.out & ./a4.out & ./a5.out & ./a6.out 

  echo fin
```

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE:

I tried like this :
cd BC_EQ

```
  nohup sh -c "gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re100_N150_Ma01_BC_Eq.f90  -o a1.out && ./a1.out " &
  nohup sh -c "gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re100_N150_Ma015_BC_Eq.f90 -o a2.out && ./a2.out " &
  nohup sh -c "gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re100_N150_Ma02_BC_Eq.f90  -o a3.out && ./a3.out " &
  nohup sh -c "gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re125_N150_Ma01_BC_Eq.f90  -o a4.out && ./a4.out " &
  nohup sh -c "gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re125_N150_Ma015_BC_Eq.f90 -o a5.out && ./a5.out " &
  nohup sh -c "gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re125_N150_Ma02_BC_Eq.f90  -o a6.out && ./a6.out " &
```

echo ja està

but eventually spits:

nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
nohup: nohup: appending output to`nohup.out'
appending output to `nohup.out'

only 4 of the 6 codes are being executed, and they do not spit anything on the screen as they used to.. why??

then if I try just :

```
    #!/bash/bin

   cd BC_EQ

   gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re100_N150_Ma01_BC_Eq.f90  -o a1.out && ./a1.out &
   gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re100_N150_Ma015_BC_Eq.f90 -o a2.out && ./a2.out &
   gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re100_N150_Ma02_BC_Eq.f90  -o a3.out && ./a3.out &
   gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re125_N150_Ma01_BC_Eq.f90  -o a4.out && ./a4.out &
   gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re125_N150_Ma015_BC_Eq.f90 -o a5.out && ./a5.out &
   gfortran -O3 -fopenmp LBM_Re125_N150_Ma02_BC_Eq.f90  -o a6.out && ./a6.out 

   echo ja està
```

it says an error: 
Fatal Error: Can't delete temporary module file 'cellconst.mod0': No such file or directory
Fatal Error: Can't delete temporary module file 'cellconst.mod0': No such file or directory
Fatal Error: Can't delete temporary module file 'cellconst.mod0': No such file or directory
Fatal Error: Can't delete temporary module file 'cellconst.mod0': No such file or directory
Fatal Error: Can't delete temporary module file 'd2q9const.mod0': No such file or directory

._·

Comment: possible duplicate of [run fortran block in bash and cancel all jobs in one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756343/run-fortran-block-in-bash-and-cancel-all-jobs-in-one)

Comment: yeah it is, I'll cancel the other post because it was not well explained

Comment: You should also learn about `batch`, `at` and possibly `crontab` commands

Answer (score 1):

Add an ampersand after the last a6.out as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here that you must add amersand after each command that you want to run in background. That means after `a6` also: `./a6.out &`.

But I would suggest you using `for` to automatize the process a little bit:

```
for i in {1..6}
do
  nohup ./a$i.out &
done
```

And you can make the compilation in parallel also:

```
for i in {1..6}
do
  nohup sh -c "gfortran -O3 code$i.f90 -o a$i.out && ./a$i.out" &
done
```

Comment: Might want to do the same with the repeated gfortran invocations too

Comment: sorry I have updated it, but anyway I have fixed by using nahuel recommendation and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 ./a1.out &
 PIDS=$!
 ./a2.out &
 PIDS="$PIDS "$!
 ./a3.out &
 PIDS="$PIDS "$!
 ./a4.out &
 PIDS="$PIDS "$!
 ./a5.out &
 PIDS="$PIDS "$!
 ./a6.out &
 PIDS="$PIDS "$!

 wait $PIDS
```

UPDATE:

$! : `man bash` `/Special Parameters` : Expands to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command.

PIDS is a variable which will contain the process ids separated by space so that expansion gives a list of arguments to wait